# where condition performance in Entity Framework query

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server database and two Entity Framework query that return same result:

**Query1**

```
var query = (from dd in db.Departments
             where (
                 from D in db.Departments
                 join DP in db.DepartmentPersonnels on D.ID equals DP.DepartmentID
                 join P in db.Personnels on DP.PersonneID equals P.ID
                 where P.UserName == Username && D.Code.IndexOf(",") >= 0
                 select D.Code.Substring(0, D.Code.IndexOf(","))).Contains(dd.Code)
                 select dd).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Query2**

```
var query = (from dd in db.Departments
             join DP in db.DepartmentPersonnels on dd.ID equals DP.DepartmentID
             join P in db.Personnels on DP.PersonneID equals P.ID
             where P.UserName.Trim().ToLower() == Username.Trim().ToLower()
             select dd).FirstOrDefault();
if (query != null)
 {
  string Code = query.Code.Split(',')[0];        
  retVal = (from d in db.Departments
  where d.Code == Code
  select d).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

I read EF performance in many posts but I didn't find information about where condition performance.

I think Query2 is better than Query1 in term of performance because `where` condition in outer `from` will be executed in SQL Server for each record.

Whether this is true?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the SQL generated - Query2 will result in 2 queries in the database

Comment: Don't guess, don't reason, *measure*. Sometimes putting everything in a single query is faster. Sometimes multiple simple queries are faster than one more complex query. You have the database. You have the C# code to access that database. You are the only one here capable of doing sensible measurements.

Comment: @hvd There is high number of records in database, In this case, I think Query2 is better.

Comment: @AliSoltani So in response to "don't guess, don't reason, *measure*", your conclusion is to attempt to reason about the best approach? Why don't you measure?

Comment: @hvd  I know I can test run time but I think they can be compared in general case.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of the 2nd query is better than 1st query is not due to the Outer `Where` clause.You must avoid these operations on the SQL server side queries (i.e.  `IQueryable`).Such as `D.Code.IndexOf(",") >= 0`,`D.Code.Substring(0, D.Code.IndexOf(","))` and `Contains`.Those operations are taking more time when you use it with the SQL Server side queries.

Do those operations after fetching the data from the server.In other words do it inside the memory (i.e `IEnumerable`).On your 2nd query there is no such time consuming operations.That is why your 2nd query shows better performance.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I know `Contains` and `IndexOf` consume time but I need to more information from `where` performance. Does it increase execution time?

Comment: yes,of course.It increases the execution time.hence it degrades the performance of the query heavily.so you have to handle those kind of time consuming operations on the memory as I mentioned above.

Comment: Where does NOT increase execution time - in most cases it will even decrease it. This is because not as many records have to be materialized - the table scan is negligible, because without Where, the whole table will be returned anyways. The problem with OP's query is that it contains filters that can not be converted into simple SQL comparisons, that's why the SQL will be rather complex and therefore will take longer - the processor will in most cases do these quicker.

Comment: Yes,that is true.I have mentioned about the problematic components of the `Where` clause.Not only about the `Where` clause.In general `Where` clause will increase the performance of the query.But OP's issue is,he has to segregate his query into 2 parts.One part is suitable for Server and other is suitable for Memory.   @DevilSuichiro

Comment: I didn't understand why `where` condition in my query increase execution time. I need more information about this.

Comment: due to this on the 1st query : `D.Code.IndexOf(",") >= 0`.You must avoid this time consuming operation on the server side.please read the above answer again.